# Return class of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I am implmenting an interface - [Codec](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/codecs/Codec.html), Which is of generic type.

It has a method like this which i need to implement

```
Class<T> getEncoderClass()
```

Now if The implementation is for simple class like this, implementation is easy -

```
public ACodec implements Codec<A>{

   public Class<A> getEncoderClass(){
        return A.class;
    }

}
```

But in case of a generic implementation i am confused how to write eg -

```
public class A<B>{
}

public ACodec implements Codec<A>{

    public Class<A<B>> getEncoderClass(){
        //How to implement this ?
    }

}
```

Comment: `ACodec` should also be defined with a type parameter. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the way you define your `ACodec` class as follows :

```
class ACodec<T> implements Codec<A<T>>{

    public Class<A<T>> getEncoderClass(){
        //How to implement this ?
    }

}
```

Here, the *type-parameter* `T` in class `ACodec`and `B` in class `A` should be substituted with the same type and I believe that's what you want to achieve. Example :

```
ACodec<String> aCodecStr = new ACodec<String>();
Class<A<String>> codecStr = aCodecStr.getEncoderClass();//works
Class<A<Integer>> codecInteger = aCodecStr.getEncoderClass();//doesn't work
```

That said, it is practically impossible to get the `Class` represented by  `A<T>` in `getEncoderClass` since *Generics* go through type-erasure at compile time itself.

Answer (score -2):

In Java generic information is lost after you compile the code (type erasure), so each generic class is also a non-generic one.

So the code in your first example should work as well.